# How to create sequence of binary file in python3?

Tags: python, binary

I want to make sequence of binary file in `python3`. The following code generates first one.

```
with open('out', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
```

the result is

```
xxd out
0000000: 0000 0000 0000 0000                      ........
```

I want to generate files which contains one of the values of sequence from `0000 0000 0000 0000` to `ffff ffff ffff ffff`.
How to do above task?

Comment: You want to generate _all_ the possible files, or just one? If it's just one, which sequence of 8 bytes should it have?

Comment: @martineau I want to just one. I want to create one file and use it for other program. Then I want to regenerate new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import struct
for i in range(0xffffffffffffffff + 1):
     with open('out{:d}'.format(i), 'wb') as f:
         f.write(struct.pack('Q', i))
```

Comment: range is not inclusive

Comment: if the code writes a million files per second then it should take only around a million years.

Answer (score 0):

The following will create one file named `out` which contains one of the possible 0x10000000000000000 different 8 byte values in the sequence (`randint` is inclusive):

```
import random
import struct

value = random.randint(0, 0xffffffffffffffff)

hexbytes = ' '.join(''.join(g) for g in zip(*[iter('{:016X}'.format(value))]*4))
print('file contains bytes {}'.format(hexbytes))

with open('out', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(struct.pack('Q', value))
```

Sample output:

```
file contains bytes EFB4 A2DC A11B 98AE
```